# 12 days of christmas, Not looping

Tags: c++

I am a fairly weak programmer and have been given the following. I have the statements set and i can clean it up when finished but for example, When user inputs '6' for example it will iterate through verse 1 to 6.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int input;

cout << "Please enter a number from 1-12, USE '999' to close." << endl;
cin >> input;

for (int input = 1; input <= 12; input++)
{

    if (input == 1)
    {
        cout << "\nOn the 1st day of Christmas my true love gave to me,\n A Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
    }

    else if (input == 2)
    {
        cout << "\nOn the 2nd day of Christmas my true love gave to me :\nTwo Turtle Doves,\n And a Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
    }
    else if (input == 3)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the 3rd day of Christmas my true love gave to me,";
        cout << "Three French Hens\nTwo Turtle Doves,\nAnd a Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
    }
    else if (input == 4)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the fourth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n";
        cout << "four Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree" << endl;
    }
    else if (input == 5)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the fifth day of Christmas my true love sent to me:\n";
        cout << " FIVE GOLDEN RINGS!, Four Calling Birds, three French Hens, 2 turtle doves\n";
        cout << "And a partridge in a pear tree.";
    }
    else if (input == 6)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the sixth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
    }
    else if (input == 7)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the seventh day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
    }
    else if (input == 8)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the eigth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (input == 9)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the nineth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (input == 10)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the tenth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \n and a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (input == 11)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the eleventh day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n11 Pipers piping,\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (input == 12)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the twevle day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n12 Drummers Drumming,\n11 Pipers piping,\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\n and a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (input == 999)
    {
        cout << "Thanks, Good bye!";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Terminating program";
        return 0;
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

thanks guys

Comment: You accept the user value as `input`, then immediately shadow that variable with the local variable `input` used as your loop counter. You should use two different names.

Comment: I think you should remove the whole `for` loop instead of renaming the variable @Cyber

Comment: @msrd0 No they shouldn't. They want to `cout` the verses from `1` up to `input`, based on what the user enters. You need the loop for this.

Comment: Renamed variable in loop to i, It now iterates through the if statement (4) until memory runs out.

Comment: @Cyber Oh sorry my fault

Comment: I see [code duplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: It always helps to **state your question** explicitly. Don't expect us to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: You should have worked with `switch` instead for `if` ladder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made a few correction on your for statement from `for (int input = 1; input <= 12; input++)` to `for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)` and changed the `input` for `i` in the if/else blocs:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int input;

cout << "Please enter a number from 1-12, USE '999' to close." << endl;
cin >> input;

for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
{

    if (i == 1)
    {
        cout << "\nOn the 1st day of Christmas my true love gave to me,\n A Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
    }

    else if (i == 2)
    {
        cout << "\nOn the 2nd day of Christmas my true love gave to me :\nTwo Turtle Doves,\n And a Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
    }
    else if (i == 3)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the 3rd day of Christmas my true love gave to me,";
        cout << "Three French Hens\nTwo Turtle Doves,\nAnd a Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
    }
    else if (i == 4)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the fourth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n";
        cout << "four Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree" << endl;
    }
    else if (i == 5)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the fifth day of Christmas my true love sent to me:\n";
        cout << " FIVE GOLDEN RINGS!, Four Calling Birds, three French Hens, 2 turtle doves\n";
        cout << "And a partridge in a pear tree.";
    }
    else if (i == 6)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the sixth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
    }
    else if (i == 7)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the seventh day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
    }
    else if (i == 8)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the eigth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (i == 9)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the nineth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (i == 10)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the tenth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \n and a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (i == 11)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the eleventh day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n11 Pipers piping,\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (i == 12)
    {
        cout << "\n\nOn the twevle day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n12 Drummers Drumming,\n11 Pipers piping,\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\n and a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

    }
    else if (i == 999)
    {
        cout << "Thanks, Good bye!";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Terminating program";
        return 0;
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

So it'll display statements from 1 to input.

Comment: This is not how you should answer on stack overflow!

Comment: I attempted the correction with the for loop. Did not work. Got further along though. I prints for example. Input = 4 then it will print 4 4 times

Comment: @KieranRichards did you change the input to i in the if blocks ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the variable on for loop. When user make input on input varialbe, the variable you've inputted changed on the for loop, so just use other variable

```
int main()
{
int input;

cout << "Please enter a number from 1-12, USE '999' to close." << endl;
cin >> input;

for (int x = 1; x <= 12; x++)
{
 // bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a homework assignment I had once.

You are resetting the input variable inside your for loop.

You can use a switch statement like this if you want to keep your code the same:

```
switch(input){
    case 1  :
       cout << "\nOn the 1st day of Christmas my true love gave to me,\n A Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
       break;
    //the rest of your cases
}
```

If you want to use the for loop you have, you're going to need to use a different variable inside your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop variable has the same name as the one you're reading into, so you're hiding the value you read, and the loop always runs from 1 to 12.

You don't need to (and it's a bad idea to) reproduce the entire contents for each number.
(The main point of this exercise is for you to discover a pattern in the song and exploit that pattern in order to avoid duplication.)

You can do this with a "break-less" switch if you don't want to loop:

```
const char* numbers[] = {"first", "second", and so on....
cout << "On the " << numbers[input - 1] << " day of Christmas my true love gave to me:\n";
switch (input)
{
    case 12: cout << "Twelve drummers drumming,\n"; // No break; fall through to next case
    case 11: cout << "Eleven pipers piping,\n";

    // ...

    case 2: cout << "Two turtle doves, and\n";
    case 1: cout << "A partridge in a pear tree\n";
}
```

or a table and a loop, if you want a loop:

```
const char* gifts[] = {"A partridge in a pear tree", ... and so on

const char* numbers[] = {"first", "second", and so on....
cout << "On the " << numbers[input - 1] << " day of Christmas my true love gave to me:\n";

for (int i = input - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     cout << gifts[i] << ",";
     if (i == 1)
         cout << " and";
     cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input;

    do
    {
        input = 999;
        cout << "Please enter a number from 1-12, USE '999' to close." << endl;

    } while ( cin >> input && input != 999 && ( input < 1 || input > 12 ) );

    if ( input == 999 )
    {
        cout << "Thanks, Good bye!";
        return 0;
    }


    for ( int i = 1; i <= input; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 1 )
        {
            cout << "\nOn the 1st day of Christmas my true love gave to me,\n A Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
        }

        else if ( i == 2 )
        {
            cout << "\nOn the 2nd day of Christmas my true love gave to me :\nTwo Turtle Doves,\n And a Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
        }
        else if ( i == 3 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the 3rd day of Christmas my true love gave to me,";
            cout << "Three French Hens\nTwo Turtle Doves,\nAnd a Partridge in a Pear Tree." << endl;
        }
        else if ( i == 4 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the fourth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n";
            cout << "four Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree" << endl;
        }
        else if ( i == 5 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the fifth day of Christmas my true love sent to me:\n";
            cout << " FIVE GOLDEN RINGS!, Four Calling Birds, three French Hens, 2 turtle doves\n";
            cout << "And a partridge in a pear tree.";
        }
        else if ( i == 6 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the sixth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
        }
        else if ( i == 7 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the seventh day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
        }
        else if ( i == 8 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the eigth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
        }
        else if ( i == 9 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the nineth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
        }
        else if ( i == 10 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the tenth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \n and a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
        }
        else if ( i == 11 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the eleventh day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n11 Pipers piping,\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves \nand a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";
        }
        else if ( i == 12 )
        {
            cout << "\n\nOn the twevle day of Christmas my true love sent to me :\n12 Drummers Drumming,\n11 Pipers piping,\n10 lords a leaping,\n9 ladies dancing,\n8 maids are milking,\n7 swans are swimming,\n6 Geese a Laying\n5 Golden Rings\n4 Calling Birds\n3 French Hens\n2 Turtle Doves\n and a Partridge in a Pear Tree\n";

        }
    }

    cout << "Terminating program";

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter 12 then the program output will be

```
Please enter a number from 1-12, USE '999' to close.

On the 1st day of Christmas my true love gave to me,
 A Partridge in a Pear Tree.

On the 2nd day of Christmas my true love gave to me :
Two Turtle Doves,
 And a Partridge in a Pear Tree.


On the 3rd day of Christmas my true love gave to me,Three French Hens
Two Turtle Doves,
And a Partridge in a Pear Tree.


On the fourth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :
four Calling Birds
3 French Hens
2 Turtle Doves
and a Partridge in a Pear Tree


On the fifth day of Christmas my true love sent to me:
 FIVE GOLDEN RINGS!, Four Calling Birds, three French Hens, 2 turtle doves
And a partridge in a pear tree.

On the sixth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :
6 Geese a Laying
5 Golden Rings
4 Calling Birds
3 French Hens
2 Turtle Doves
and a Partridge in a Pear Tree


On the seventh day of Christmas my true love sent to me :
7 swans are swimming,
6 Geese a Laying
5 Golden Rings
4 Calling Birds
3 French Hens
2 Turtle Doves
and a Partridge in a Pear Tree


On the eigth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :
8 maids are milking,
7 swans are swimming,
6 Geese a Laying
5 Golden Rings
4 Calling Birds
3 French Hens
2 Turtle Doves
and a Partridge in a Pear Tree


On the nineth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :
9 ladies dancing,
8 maids are milking,
7 swans are swimming,
6 Geese a Laying
5 Golden Rings
4 Calling Birds
3 French Hens
2 Turtle Doves 
and a Partridge in a Pear Tree


On the tenth day of Christmas my true love sent to me :
10 lords a leaping,
9 ladies dancing,
8 maids are milking,
7 swans are swimming,
6 Geese a Laying
5 Golden Rings
4 Calling Birds
3 French Hens
2 Turtle Doves 
 and a Partridge in a Pear Tree


On the eleventh day of Christmas my true love sent to me :
11 Pipers piping,
10 lords a leaping,
9 ladies dancing,
8 maids are milking,
7 swans are swimming,
6 Geese a Laying
5 Golden Rings
4 Calling Birds
3 French Hens
2 Turtle Doves 
and a Partridge in a Pear Tree


On the twevle day of Christmas my true love sent to me :
12 Drummers Drumming,
11 Pipers piping,
10 lords a leaping,
9 ladies dancing,
8 maids are milking,
7 swans are swimming,
6 Geese a Laying
5 Golden Rings
4 Calling Birds
3 French Hens
2 Turtle Doves
 and a Partridge in a Pear Tree
Terminating program
```

Answer (score -3):

That's because you are creating a new variable inside your for loop hiding your input created before.
If I understood correctly, you can just use something like

```
for (; input <= 12; input++)
//more code
```

Comment: I gave you a downvote because it does not what the OP wants: _`When user inputs '6' for example it will iterate through verse 1 to 6`_

Comment: Its Christmas, Thank you all for the help. Stress has no eased. Thank you all!